# Error by Node JS request to external service with required p12 certificat

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, certificate, ssl-certificate

There is a service which provides a XML under a certain URL (for example: https://myxml). The organisation from that service send me a p12 certificate with the password.
In the Browser it works correct.
On my local machine I'm running a Node JS server. I want to send a request from my node server and get the response from the service.

I'm pretty new to certificates.

This is the error I get after trying to get the request from the service

```
error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
```

This is the implementation in the node server

```
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const certFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'folder/cert.p12');

var options = {
  url: 'https://myxml',
  cert: fs.readFileSync(certFile),
  passphrase: 'xyz'
}


request.get(options);
request('https://myxml', function(error, response, body){
  console.log("error: ", error);
  console.log("statusCode: ", response && response.statusCode);
  console.log("body: ", body);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading the file in as binary and using it directly

```
var p12 = fs.readFileSync('file.p12', 'binary');
var p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(p12, false);
var p12Parsed = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(p12Asn1, false, 'password');
```

also add `agentOptions` in request like

```
request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://myxml',
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    strictSSL: false, 
    agentOptions: {
        //pfx: pfx,
        pfx: require('fs').readFileSync('string_path_to_the_p12_key_file.p12'),
        passphrase: 'redacted_password'
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I will give it a try but now I get the error: `Cannot read property 'fromDer' of undefined`

Comment: ok there are no errors with agentOptions but I also receive no response

Comment: Ok the agentOptions method works but the response are glyphs like `...J��S��ӵP���cM�R���H����@@,�oUc���n...`

Comment: it works now. that problem was, the response was gziped